# Expand array elements appending a string to each in a loop

Tags: json, bash, jq

Hopefully someone could point me in the right direction!

My input:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    "bob.doe",
    "joe.gomez",
    "bill.murr"
  ]
}
```

My attempt:

```sh
acc=$(cat $file |  jq -r  '.accounts[]' )
echo "$acc test"
```

Output:

```
bob.doe
joe.gomez
bill.murr test
```

It seems to treat all the values in JSON as one array object.

Desired output:

```
bob.doe test
joe.gomez test
bill.murr test
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `acc` is assigned the entire output of JQ, there's no loop there. And you don't need one either.

```
$ jq -r '"\(.accounts[]) test"' file
bob.doe test
joe.gomez test
bill.murr test
```

Comment: how would the code change if you want to do the exact same thing for all elements **but** the last one? Tried `jq -r '"\(.accounts[:-1]) test"'` but its not quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

thanks this got me on the right path!

```
sa=$(cat $file |  jq -r  '"\\n \"\(.service_accounts[])\" = [\"\(.namespace)\"]"')
```